# pkgconfig(alsa) in spec file doesn't recognize already installed alsa, alsa-devel

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild, pkg-config

I'm trying to build qt on CentOS 5.6
but it fails with the reason that the system doesn't have required libraries.

I'm trying to build with source and spec file from the Fedora qt source rpm file.

$ rpmbuild -ba qt.spec

and the fail message is like below,

```
    pkgconfig(alsa) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(dbus-1) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(fontconfig) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(glib-2.0) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(icu-i18n) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(NetworkManager) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(openssl) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(libpng) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(libpulse) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xtst) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(zlib) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(ice) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(sm) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xcursor) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xext) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xfixes) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xft) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xi) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xinerama) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xrandr) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xrender) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xt) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xv) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(x11) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(xproto) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(gl) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(glu) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(gstreamer-0.10) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(gtk+-2.0) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
    pkgconfig(sqlite3) is needed by qt-4.8.2-4.noarch
```

but most of the above ( alsa-devel, fontconfig ...etc ) are already installed.
and .pc files are in '/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/'

I think rpmbuild can not recognize 'pkgconfig(...)'.

can anybody know the reason ?
plz help me~

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change alsa-devel to alsa-lib-devel in spec file

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` within the build environment:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
```

Take a look at [this old bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=212522) for some more insight regarding this advice.